# Close current window using cmd?

Tags: batch-file, cmd, batch-processing

Is this possible to close current window using cmd?
i use this [here is a link](https://superuser.com/questions/859043/need-batch-file-to-close-a-window-not-the-batch-window) but in vain.

Comment: The running command process processing a batch file can be exited independent on calling hierarchy with command __exit__ used in the batch file. But please note that on using __exit__ without parameter `/B` results in always exiting command process even when the batch file is executed from within a command prompt window started implicit with parameter `/K` to keep the command process running and the console window opened after finishing processing of batch file. That is not good for debugging a batch file by executing it from within a cmd window. Run `exit /?` in a cmd window for details.

Comment: Thanks for comment!
Sorry for TAG "Power Shell" i have remove it

Answer (score -1):

Create a .bat file script named `closeme.bat` in the current directory or a directory that is in your `PATH` variable.

```
@ECHO OFF
ECHO This is a batch file script.
EXIT
```

Run the `closeme.bat` script.

```
CALL closeme.bat
```

The current window will close.